# Using collate in Solr Suggester Component?

Tags: solr

**Usecase**

Our Solr index contains documents of many countries. Some documents should be only visible in some countries.
Thus suggestions provided to a user in the USA should only contain documents visible in the USA.

**Approaches to solving the problem**

a) When I'm using the [Solr SpellCheckComponent for suggestions](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester), I can activate **collate=true**. This will filter the suggestions to all provided Solr filter queries.
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/suggest?fq=country:us&q=pro

b) But I want to use advanced suggesters, such as AnalyzingInfixSuggester, so I have to use the Solr [SuggestComonent](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html). Unfortunately I can't find a way to activate **collate**. Thus my filter queries are ignored for the suggestions, and all products for all countries are returned.

**Questions**

a) Is there a way, to activate collate in SuggestComponent?

b) Or is it possible to use advanced suggesters with the SpellCheckComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for [Context Filtering](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html#Suggester-ContextFiltering). That feature is what you use to filter some suggestions with the advanced suggesters.

Add this row to the suggester configuration:

```
<str name="contextField">country</str>
```

Add the request parameter to the suggest query:

```
suggest.cfq=us
```

Comment: This works! But there's no way to use real filter queries with the suggester (they are more versatile than contextField)?

Comment: no, you don't have all the flexibility of a fq there. If it's a predefined fq, you can compute it into a field at index time and use that field as cfq.